# How can I play NetHack MacOS X Tiles Port (NetHack QT) on Mac OS 12.1?

Tags: macos, nethack

I found it won't work when I run NetHack QT 3.4.3 on my Mac OS when I upgrade to Montery.

But where can I get it for Montery?